# google assistant on pi3

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, google-assistant-sdk

So I'm new to the raspberry firm and I'm kinda stuck in the middle of something was planning to start up with google assistant everything is fine I made the required `.json` file but could not generate the link
 after entering the code line.

````
google-oauthlib-tool --scope https://www.googleapis.com/auth/assistant-sdk-prototype \
  --scope https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gcm \
  --save --headless --client-secrets /path/to/client_secret_client-id.json```
````

I get this

```
        google-oauthlib-tool --scope https://www.googleapis.com/auth/assistant-sdk-prototype \
    >       --scope https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gcm \
    >       --save --headless --client-secrets /path/to/client_secret_.json
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/pi/env/bin/google-oauthlib-tool", line 10, in <module>
        sys.exit(main())
      File "/home/pi/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 722, in __call__
        return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
      File "/home/pi/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 697, in main
        rv = self.invoke(ctx)
      File "/home/pi/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 895, in invoke
        return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
      File "/home/pi/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/click/core.py", line 535, in invoke
        return callback(*args, **kwargs)
      File "/home/pi/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google_auth_oauthlib/tool/__main__.py", line 100, in main
        scopes=scope
      File "/home/pi/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google_auth_oauthlib/flow.py", line 196, in from_client_secrets_file
        with open(client_secrets_file, 'r') as json_file:
    FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/path/to/client_secret.json
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

in Flow.py, the directory file you are passing in does not exist, it is still trying to call path/to/client_secret.json. This line was copy and pasted from somewhere else so you need to update the client_secrets_file variable with the real path to the json file.

If you provided more code I could help further.

Comment: I was using this site as a guide    https://www.hackster.io/Salmanfarisvp/googlepi-google-assistant-on-raspberry-pi-9f3677